# CanCan to define and check ability to "login in" with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

Is it possible to define cancan for anonymous users in devise?  Where an anonymous user "can" log in, a logged in user "cannot".

Can I define cancan abilities for anonymous users, or should I avoid cancan for anonymous users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand the question completely.  You can certainly allow anonymous users to do stuff with cancan

```
#anyone can see this stuff
can :read, [Contact, Question, UserAction, Provider, Organisation]

#only users that are managers can do this
if user.can_manage_data?
  can :manage, [Contact, Organisation, UserAction]
end
```

But I think you are actually asking 'can you allow anonymous users to do something that signed in users cannot?  That's not something I've done, but i presume that you can use

```
#noone can see this stuff
cannot :read, [Contact, Question, UserAction, Provider, Organisation]
```

If the question is specifically about logging in though - i think that is a subtly different problem - a user *can* read an article (or not), but a user *is* logged in (or not) and in this specific case I don't think cancan is the right answer

Comment: Those examples are very helpful for general ability definitions. Re. checking login status, is it risky or otherwise wrong to use CanCan for that by filtering for user.id.nil? See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I also wondered about this, e.g. how do I only allow account creation when no user is signed in?

Of course one can do this with Devise, by adding before_filters to the controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new, :create]
before_filter :user_signed_out,    :only   => [:new, :create]
```

then add this at the end of the controller:

```
private
  def user_signed_out
    if user_signed_in?
      flash[:alert] = "You are already signed in as #{current_user.email}."
      redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end
```

However it seems I can accomplish the same thing in the CanCan Ability.rb:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
can :create, Account if user.id.nil?
```

Still pretty new to this so I'd welcome confirmation or correction.